# Startup Broadcast Receiver Not Running At Startup

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a class StartupReceiver:

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, ARMRService.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
```

and it is declared in my Manifest.xml as

```
<receiver android:name=".StartupReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

and I have given the correct permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Why is this not working???

Comment: Is the StartupReceiver inside your package defined for the application or in a separate package?

Comment: Seems like it should work, are you sure it's not just a problem in that service? Have you tried adding a log line or toast in your BroadcastReceiver to see?

Comment: yes, its defined in the same application in the same package.

Comment: @kabuko I have put a Log in and it doesnt print it. HOWEVER, there is nothing wrong with the service because when I start it from button click it works perfectly. Just not from startup....

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good to me. Could you add some logs in onReceive() and check whether that is invoked on bootup or not. There can some issues in the service which is to be started.

Comment: I did. is it possible that it doesnt log to the LogCat because the debugger hasn't attached yet?

Comment: Logcat gets attached on the phone bootup itself. Dont you not get the phone boot logs in DDMS. Ideally it should be available. Just for debugging purpose, why not replace your service with a dummy service?

Comment: Its not the service because when I start it from button click it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, I just learned that  as of Android 3.0 the user needs to have started the application at least once before your application can receive android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED events. Could this be a possible cause of why its not starting the service?